# Android Overlay a portion of bitmap on top of another using a clipping path (or any other method)

Tags: android, graphics, path, 2d, clipping

Android 2.1 or greater

Suppose I have two images that are the same size, one is a donut shape with transparency in the middle and outside the donut.

The other is a square image that is the same size as the donut

If they were overlayed they would look something like this (the donut would actually not be visible since the square would be on top of the Z stack)

[image: Figure 1]

What I would like to do is create a clipping path or any method really to display the portion of the square bitmap that falls inside the donut using a starting and stopping angle (which would change over time)

So for instance show the portion of blue square that is inside the donut starting at 0 degrees and ending at 40 degrees, as well as 180 and 270 degrees. Which would produce something like this.

Not even sure where to start, anyone have any ideas?

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried myself but [clipPath(Path path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) might be what you are looking for. The hard part would be to setup the correct path to do the clipping with.

Comment: Yes I did get that far, actually I have a solution since it was left open so long, I will probably put that up shortly and see if anyone can optimize it.